# How to erase "about:blank" from URL with a RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, remove

Want to delete the `about:blank` from a URL `www.example.com/camera/about:blank`. How can I do this with `.htaccess`? I tried `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (about:blank) [NC]` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> delete the `about:blank` from a URL `www.example.com/camera/about:blank`

In the URL as posted, `about:blank` is part of the URL-path, not the query string, so you can match this as-is in the `RewriteRule` pattern. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(camera/)about:blank$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` backreference simply saves repetition. This contains the "camera/" part of the URL-path, as captured from the requested URL-path.

If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 301 only once you have confirmed that it works OK - to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it! :-)

Comment: How did you get on with this?